# rosjava install fail

Tags: ros, rosjava-core, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi. i have a question

i'm setting up rosjava now using this page.
http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/rosjava_core/html/installing.html

but.. FAIL !!

please tell me the reason... i don't know why..TT..

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39241/rosjava-install-fail/) by [SanghaNam](https://answers.ros.org/users/2025/sanghanam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 54 on 2012-07-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As the error message suggests, it seems on your system, the mercurial client (hg) is not installed.
Try

```
sudo aptitude install mercurial
```

Or check google for install instructions of Mercurial for your system.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2012-07-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SanghaNam](https://answers.ros.org/users/2025/sanghanam/) on 2012-07-19**:
i really appreciate your help !! thank you !!